# Unexpected behavior of python builtin str function

Tags: python

I am running into an issue with subtyping the str class because of the `str.__call__` behavior I apparently do not understand.

This is best illustrated by the simplified code below.

```
class S(str):
    def __init__(self, s: str):
        assert isinstance(s, str)
        print(s)

class C:
    def __init__(self, s: str):
        self.s = S(s)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.s

c = C("a")  # -> prints "a"
c.__str__() # -> does not print "a"
str(c)      # -> asserts fails in debug mode, else prints "a" as well!?
```

I always thought the `str(obj)` function simply calls the `obj.__str__` method, and that's it. But for some reason it also calls the `__init__` function of `S` again.
Can someone explain the behavior and how I can avoid that `S.__init__` is called on the result of `C.__str__` when using the `str()` function?

Comment: Which version of Python are you running? For 2.7, `str(c)` hangs on me while `c.__str__()` prints a.

Comment: `str` is not a function, it's a class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, `str` isn't a function. It's a type. When you call `str(c)`, Python goes through the normal procedure for generating an instance of a type, calling `str.__new__(str, c)` to create the object (or reuse an existing object), **and then calling the `__init__` method of the result to initialize it**.

[`str.__new__(str, c)`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#l3697) calls the C-level function [`PyObject_Str`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/object.c#l448), which calls [`_PyObject_Str`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/object.c#l406), which calls your `__str__` method. The result is an instance of `S`, so it counts as a string, and `_PyObject_Str` decides this is good enough rather than trying to coerce an object with `type(obj) is str` out of the result. Thus, `str.__new__(str, c)` returns `c.s`.

Now we get to `__init__`. Since the argument to `str` was `c`, this also gets passed to `__init__`, so Python calls `c.s.__init__(c)`. `__init__` calls `print(c)`, which you might think would call `str(c)` and lead to infinite recursion. However, the [`PRINT_ITEM`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/ceval.c#l1962) opcode calls the C-level [PyFile_WriteObject](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#l2546) to write the object, and that calls `PyObject_Str` instead of `str`, so it skips the `__init__` and doesn't recurse infinitely. Instead, it calls `c.__str__()` and prints the resulting `S` instance, as the `S` instance is a string.

Comment: I think I got it. The `__init__` is part of the normal sequence behind a `__call__` (i.e. a `__new__` followed by a `__init__`). I didn't thought about that. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: The fact that the `C` object is used as argument for the `__init__`, that's the real tricky/not-intuitive thing here. If I use annotations with run-time checks, and in case of failure print the object info via a `str()` call, then I have an infinite recursion. This case is actually the trigger for my question. Wondering how to workaround? Maybe always use `__str__` directly instead of a `str()`?

Comment: @pfp.meijers: Why do you even have this weird `str` subclass with its really weird `__init__`? I would recommend having your `__str__` return an object with `type(obj) is str`. If you really want to use this weird `str` subclass, you should probably have it implement `__new__` instead of `__init__`.

Comment: The `str` subclass is weird because I simplified it here for illustration purposes. But your suggestion to return a `type(obj) is str` will do the job. So that is how I will solve it. Thanks!