# Returning int from a __str__ method in Python

Tags: python, string, cpython, python-internals

I know, that the purpose of `str()` method is to return the string representation of an object, so I wanted to test what happens if I force it to make something else.

I've created a class and an object:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __str__(self, a=2, b=3):
        return a + b

mc = MyClass()
```

When I call:

```
print(str(mc))
```

The interpreter complains:

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type int)
```

And this is fully understandable because the str() method is trying to return **int**.

But if I try:

```
print(mc.__str__())
```

I get the output: 5.

So why the interpreter allows me to return int when I call `__str__` directly, but not when I'm using str(mc) which - as I understand - is also evaluated to `mc.__str__()`.

Comment: I'm interested to understand why also

Comment: You might find this link here useful ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448175/confused-about-str-on-list-in-python

Comment: This explains a bit how overriding of `__str__` works in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144026/how-to-define-a-str-method-for-a-class

Comment: The `str` function *does* call `__str__`, but it enforces the `str` return type also. It's not simply a direct call to `__str__`

Comment: Does this therefore count as an omission of the documentation? According to the docs, `str` (with a single argument) just calls `__str__` -- it makes no reference to checking the type.

Comment: @Denziloe well, in the [data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) it does state that `__str__` must return a `str`.

Answer (score 5):

`str()` calls [`PyObject_Str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Str). [Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/master/Objects/object.c) is the source code where `PyObject_Str()` is defined. If you search this document for "`__str__`", you will see where the function calls `__str__` and makes sure the return type is actually a string.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah good point, that's rather extraneous here.

Answer (score 4):

The built-in `str` function (and also `repr`) do more than just calling `.__str__` (or `.__repr__`) – they also have defaults to cope with objects that don't have a `__str__` or `__repr__` method, and some cleverness to deal with objects whose string representation is recursive.

You can see the source (in C) for `str` and `repr` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/caba55b3b735405b280273f7d99866a046c18281/Objects/object.c#L490) and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/caba55b3b735405b280273f7d99866a046c18281/Objects/object.c#L443). As you can see, they enforce the return type of `__str__` and `__repr__`:

```
if (!PyUnicode_Check(res)) {
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                 "__str__ returned non-string (type %.200s)",
                 Py_TYPE(res)->tp_name);
    Py_DECREF(res);
    return NULL;
}
```

If you just call the `__str__` method on an object, Python itself doesn't enforce that any method called `__str__` can only return a string – it's the `str` function that enforces that restriction.

Answer (score 2):

`str` isn't just

```
def str(obj):
    return obj.__str__()
```

I think very few of the standard functions or operators map *directly* to a magic method like that, although I'm not sure of the exact counts.

`str` tries `__str__`, but it also tries `__repr__` if there's no `__str__`, and it enforces the `str` return type. (It also calls the return value's `__init__` for technical reasons, [which can get weird for `str` subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859471/unexpected-behavior-of-python-builtin-str-function).) `+` tries `__add__`, but it also tries `__radd__`. `iter` tries `__iter__`, but it also tries `__getitem__`. The list goes on and on.

Answer (score -1):

`__str__` provides a contract: you return a string, and the program won't break when it tries to use a non-string value when the program expects a string. Determining whether `__str__` actually *obeys* that contract is uncomputable in general, so it is up to the programmer to enforce the contract.

As @Juanpa.arrivillaga points out, `str` is simply stricter about the `__str__` method returning what it should be. Your explicit call to `__str__` doesn't actually invoke the protocol; it returns an `int` value, but that value itself has a `__str__` method which `print` calls when it wants a `str` value.